Is it true that $[A,G]\cap [B,G]=[A\cap B,G]$?
Let $G$ be a group and let $A$ and $B$ be two (maybe normal) subgroups of $G$. Is it true that:
$$[A,G]\cap [B,G]=[A\cap B,G].$$
It is clear that $[A\cap B,G]\leq [A,G]\cap [B,G]$. But is the other inclusion true.
Something similar was asked in Mathoverflow some years ago. Where this question appeared in on of the comments, but it was never answered.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294822/do-commutator-functor-and-intersection-commute
Thanks for your help!

The question in the comments there was whether $A\cap[B,B]=[A,A]\cap[B,B]$  when $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of a free group $F$ and $A$ is generated by some of the free generators of $F$. A different question altogether.

Also, please avoid titles that consist of nothing but MathJax code; they break some navigational shortcuts.

It is false. Let $G=Q_8=\langle i,j,k\rangle$ be the quaternion group of order $8$. Consider the subgroups $A=\langle i\rangle$, $B=\langle j\rangle$. As $A\cap B=\{1,-1\}=\textbf Z(G)$ then $[A\cap B,G]=1$, but $-1\in[A,G]\cap [B,G]$ since
$$[i,j]=i^{-1}j^{-1}ij=(-i)(-j)ij=k^2=-1\in[A,G]$$
and
$$[j,i]=j^{-1}i^{-1}ji=(-j)(-i)ji=(-k)(-k)=k^2=-1\in[B,G].$$

Even smaller counterexample: let $G=S_3$ and $A=\langle (12) \rangle$, $B=\langle (13) \rangle$. Since the center of $G$ is trivial, $1 \lt [A,G] \subseteq [G,G]=A_3$. And similarly for $B$. Hence $[A,G]=A_3=[B,G]$. But $A \cap B=1$, so $[A \cap B,G]=1$. 
If you replace $B$ above by $A_3$, you reach the same contradiction, showing that normality does not matter.
